# Time sensitive free startup manager

Tags: open-source, windows-10

I want to startup certain programs on specific days from bootup,on Windows 10. Chameleon startup manager does this but charges for it.

Comment: From hibernation?  Any other requirements?

Comment: From a cold start.

Comment: So you mean that on Monday, a certain service gets started on cold boot, on Tuesday, another, ... (and only on cold boot?)  Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Xecutor](http://download.cnet.com/Xecutor/3000-2094_4-10403543.html)** startups programs at specific times and days of the week (no calendar).

It runs in addition to your existing startup routine, so disable everything you would prefer to start with Xecutor. Manually adding programs is a pain, but it painlessly imports (and deletes) shortcuts from your startup folder.